# laravel scheduler withoutOverlapping when using queues (database)

Tags: php, laravel, queue, schedule

I have always used the sync queue driver and had some long running jobs in my scheduler (up to an hour):

```
$schedule->job(new ProcessFileUploads())->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping(60);
```

The withoutOverlapping worked fine when in sync mode, but now I have changed the driver to `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` and the job gets written to the DB jobs table every minute, even though the old job might still be running.

How am I supposed to handle this case?

Comment: Which server using?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar Azure WebApp

Comment: Did you encountered any problem in your usual job execution?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar You mean, when using the sync driver? Everything worked fine with it. But I now need to use the database driver.

Comment: No am asking did you changed driver to database & followed steps in Laravel doc? After this configuration did you got any issue?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar The queue worker works fine. My problem is with the scheduler adding the jobs to the queue. I need to make sure there are not multiple instances of the same job added to the queue.

Comment: It depends upon your logic & code

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way

Create a command file https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#generating-commands

Then include the command class inside app\Console\Kernel.php

```
$schedule->command('Process:FileUploads')->withoutOverlapping(60);
```

In your command file inside handle()

```
   /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        dispatch(new ProcessFileUploads());

    }
```

This is a good way to work with jobs & Schedulers

You can make use of https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#job-events for tracking your job activities